# C# Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point

Tags: c#

I imitate this code exactly as tutorials, video tutorials success but after I try, I get an error message
When I try to compile I get the message:

```
does not contain a static 'main' method suitable for an entry point.
```

its my code

```
using System;

    class program
    {
        static void main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Input your name");

            string UserName = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("your name" + UserName);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to make it public. `public static void Main()`. `Main` is also capitalized following the coding best practices of methods in C#.

Comment: Main with capital M

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to write name like

```
static void Main()
{
}
```

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228506(v=vs.90).aspx)

> Every C# application must contain a single Main method specifying
>   where program execution is to begin. In C#, Main is capitalized, while
>   Java uses lowercase main.

Comment: Yup.  For C# 'Main' is a keyword.  'main' is not.

Answer (score 0):

Write it like this public static void Main() 
Main has to be capitalized